# Как распарсить строку JSON на php?

Tags: json, php

Есть строка

```
  = {
    "response": [64, {
        "pid": "114272714",
        "aid": "33565378",
        "owner_id": "5005272",
        "created": "1214309659",
        "src": "http:\/\/cs1437.vkontakte.ru\/u5005272\/33565378\/m_2a07b7cb.jpg",
        "src_big": "http:\/\/cs1437.vkontakte.ru\/u5005272\/33565378\/x_5769a2b7.jpg",
        "src_small": "http:\/\/cs1437.vkontakte.ru\/u5005272\/33565378\/s_beb1d458.jpg",
        "text": "test"
    }]
}
```

Нужно ее распарсить, вся проблема в этом: `{"response":[64,{"pid`! Как распарсить на php?

Comment: А если попробовать на JS?

Answer (score 15):

Эм.. [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)?

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["response"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(64)
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#2 (8) {
      ["pid"]=>
      string(9) "114272714"
      ["aid"]=>
      string(8) "33565378"
      ["owner_id"]=>
      string(7) "5005272"
      ["created"]=>
      string(10) "1214309659"
      ["src"]=>
      string(59) "http://cs1437.vkontakte.ru/u5005272/33565378/m_2a07b7cb.jpg"
      ["src_big"]=>
      string(59) "http://cs1437.vkontakte.ru/u5005272/33565378/x_5769a2b7.jpg"
      ["src_small"]=>
      string(59) "http://cs1437.vkontakte.ru/u5005272/33565378/s_beb1d458.jpg"
      ["text"]=>
      string(4) "test"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: мой звездный час :)